# Alter CSS of div when another div is hovering on top

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a sortable list as follows:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"> </script>

  <style>
      .sortableItem {
          height: 50px;
          width: 300px;
          border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          padding-top: 10px;
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: bold;
          border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
          background-color: #e7f0fe;
          color: gray;
          margin: 3px;
      }

      .sortableItem:hover {
          cursor: pointer;
      }



      #sortable {
          float: left;
      }

      #sortable1 {
          float: right;
      }

      #times {
          float: left;
      }

      .day {
            cursor: not-allowed;
          background-color:#4885ed;
          color: white;
      }

      .swapable {
          z-index:  10;
      }

      .swapable:hover {
          color: #4885ed;
      }



  </style>

  <script>


      $(function() {
$(".swapable").
draggable({ revert: true }).
droppable({
    drop:function(event,ui){
        swapNodes($(this).get(0),$(ui.draggable).get(0));
    }});
});


function swapNodes(a, b) {
var aparent= a.parentNode;
var asibling= a.nextSibling===b? a : a.nextSibling;
b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
aparent.insertBefore(b, asibling);
}

  </script>

  </head>

  <body>

   <button id="click">Click me</button>





   <script>


    /* $("#click").click(function() {
        var hotelOrder = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

     hotelOrder.push(sortable.children[i].innerHTML);
    $("#test"+i).html(hotelOrder[i]);
        } 
    }) */

   </script>

   <div id = "sortable" class="ui-state">

        <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default day">Monday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable1">Hotel 1</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable2">Hotel 2</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable3">Hotel 3</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable4">Hotel 4</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable5">Hotel 5</div>



          <div class = "sortableItem day">Tuesday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable6">Hotel 6</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable7">Hotel 7</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable8">Hotel 8</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable9">Hotel 9</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable10">Hotel 10</div>


          <div class = "sortableItem day">Wednesday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable11">Hotel 11</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable12">Hotel 12</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable13">Hotel 13</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable14">Hotel 14</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable15">Hotel 15</div>


          <div class = "sortableItem day">Thursday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable16">Hotel 16</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable17">Hotel 17</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable18">Hotel 18</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable19">Hotel 19</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable20">Hotel 20</div>


         <div class = "sortableItem day">Friday</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable21">Hotel 21</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable22">Hotel 22</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable23">Hotel 23</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable24">Hotel 24</div>
         <div class = "sortableItem swapable ui-state-default" id="draggable25">Hotel 25</div>

      </div>

   <script>


  $('.swapable').mouseover(function() {
 // set ohters element to the initial level
 $(this).siblings('.swapable').css('z-index', 10);
 // set clicked element to a higher level
 $(this).css('z-index', 11);
 });

   </script>
```

So I have my Sortable element and I can swap divs around by dragging one and dropping on top of another. The effect I would like to achieve is as follows - when I drag a particular element to another one's position, I want the div that I am hovering over to be highlighted so that the use knows that they are in the correct position to drop the div. So for example, let's say I want to switch #draggable2 with #draggable6, when I drag #draggable2 to #draggable6, I want #droppable6 to be highlighted before I drop the element so that I know I am in the right place.

I tried #droppable6:hover but that clearly doesn't work. If anyone has any ideas...

Comment: you don't have droppable6 class or id in your code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery UI, just add CSS declarations for `.ui-droppable-active` like:

```
.ui-droppable-active {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    /* other styles */
}
```

This is built-in to the widget, per [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/):

> The droppable widget uses the jQuery UI CSS framework to style its look and feel. If droppable specific styling is needed, the following CSS class names can be used for overrides or as keys for the classes option:
>
> ui-droppable-active class is added. When dragging a draggable over
>   this droppable, the ui-droppable-hover class is added.

**EDIT:**

If this doesn't get you where you need to go, you can define a `hoverClass` parameter when you setup `.droppable()`.

CSS:

```
.rollover {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    /* other styles */
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".swapable").
draggable({ revert: true }).
droppable({
    hoverClass: "rollover", /* <- added this */
    drop:function(event,ui){
        swapNodes($(this).get(0),$(ui.draggable).get(0));
    }});
});
```